# Can a machine process and run on $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ for an $O_2$ by product?

Tags: mars, colonization, oxygen, gasses

On Mars studies have shown that carbon dioxide solidifies to dry ice at the poles. During the winter months can electrolysis be applied to collected and then contained liquid $CO_2$ to replenish oxygen reserves by creating an engine that uses $CO_2$ as the oxidizer?

Could solar powered electrolysis of liquid $CO_2$ and $H_2O$ during the summer provide liquid $O_2$ and Hydrogen to power a generator in place of using batteries for electrical storage for generator during winter?

What can be added to liquid CO<sub>2</sub> to allow better electrolysis to crack $CO_2$ or to used as an oxidizer for $CO_2$ combustion engine?

The main component of the atmosphere of Mars is carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) at 95.9%. Each pole is in continual darkness during its hemisphere's winter, and the surface gets so cold that as much as 25% of the atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> condenses at the polar caps into solid CO<sub>2</sub> ice (dry ice). When the pole is again exposed to sunlight during summer, the CO<sub>2</sub> ice sublimes back into the atmosphere. This process leads to a significant annual variation in the atmospheric pressure and atmospheric composition around the Martian poles.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Mars

$CO_2$ sublimes but it can be self collected in vast containers or an underground cave that can be capped open during winter, closed and kept as a super liquid during summer to power generators similar to steam engines?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66265/can-co2-be-broken-into-its-component-elements-by-electrolysis

[Martian Carbon Dioxide Turbine Oxygen Generator](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31724/martian-carbon-dioxide-turbine-oxygen-generator)

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112136/what-is-the-ideal-temperature-to-crack-water

Comment: Can you show the study that liquid CO2 forms naturally on Mars?

Comment: Looks better! I think the word "liquifies" in the first sentence still needs to go. It goes straight from gas to solid, just like frost forming on windows in the winter (at least in places where it's cold enough).

Comment: If the energy source is sunlight, or nuclear fission, why not just store it in batteries instead of engaging in chemical fuel manufacturing? Batteries are simple, reliable, storable, partitionable and mobile. And electric engines and other uses of electricity are efficient and versatile. Batteries in space are like gold is good as money.

Comment: @localFluff Batteries are expensive if you want to store gigawatt years of power. Pumping gas into a large cavern under pressure, or making methane and oxygen from CO2 and water (or, more difficult but doesn't need water, making carbon monoxide and oxygen from CO2) are more scalable.

Comment: @SteveLinton - creating underground fuel stores worked on Earth because plants came long before people.  Do you think we will put the storage tools on Mars that long before people show up to spend it?

Comment: @aml I'm not suggesting burying plants ave waiting for them to turn into fuel. I'm suggesting making fuel gases ourselves, using nuclear or solar power and then storing them underground for a few months or years until they are need ed

Comment: @SteveLinton Corverted atmosphere at a pole oxygen, hydrogen and water could be stored without  pressurization.

Comment: @Muze, yes, if you have a big enough space. On the other hand, compressing the gas is an additional way to store energy.

Comment: @SteveLinton That was a part of the original it but was split into this one: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31724/martian-carbon-dioxide-turbine-oxygen-generator

Comment: ABSOLUTELY NOT is the obvious answer. I mean the usual machines here on earth use either O2 and C (some carbon at least) or H and O2 to PRODUCE energy. Your plan is to take the waste of energy-producing reactions and magically make something run with it

Comment: Why does mars appear to be rotating backwards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can electrolysis of water provide fuel for the generator where both water and liquid carbon dioxide is utilized in one self sustaining machine?

**NO**. A 'self sustaining machine' would be a perpetual motion machine, and those are impossible. You have to provide energy from an external source.

Electrolysis of water costs energy, about [50 kWh per kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water#Efficiency) of hydrogen produced, the process is about 80% efficient. So when you burn that hydrogen, you can recover 80% of the energy you used to electrolyze it. And part of that 80% is lost converting the heat (from burning the hydrogen) into usable forms of energy (motion, electricity). Fuel cells are about 80% efficient. You can also burn the hydrogen in an internal combustion engine, but those are usually less than 50% efficient.

Similarly, cracking CO<sub>2</sub> costs a lot of energy.

Current processes for cracking CO<sub>2</sub> use H<sub>2</sub> to react with CO<sub>2</sub> to [reduce the CO<sub>2</sub> to CO plus H<sub>2</sub>O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_reduction_of_carbon_dioxide).

NASA [is investigating ways](https://www.nasa.gov/content/direct-generation-of-oxygen-via-electrocatalytic-reduction-of-carbon-dioxide-in-an-ionic/) to reduce CO<sub>2</sub> directly to carbon and O<sub>2</sub>.

> Could we not add something to liquid CO<sub>2</sub> to allow better electrolysis?

Possibly, yes. That's the subject of NASA's research: to find an ionic liquid that can serve as a catalyst for CO<sub>2</sub> reduction.

Comment: If a ionic liquid is found to split CO2 by electrolysis, electric energy is still necessary. The ionic liquid does not serve as a catalyst to split CO2, it serves as an electrolyte in order to let an electric current flow.

Comment: From the linked article: "Electrochemically reducing CO2 is normally a very energy intensive process. However, ILs have properties that let them act as both CO2 absorbers and reduction catalysts, effectively decreasing the required energy to recycle CO2. "

Comment: Electricity supplied externally could be used on Mars will crack CO2 to make O2 for fuel. I was not talking about a self-perpetuating machine.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about using summertime sunlight to electrolize water and/or carbon dioxide into storable fuels for consumption during polar winter when there is no sunlight, not build a perpetual motion machine.

Answer (score 6):

**note:** the question has been significantly modified (potentially improved) - I'll leave this slightly-outdated answer here as-is for reference.

There probably are no studies that have shown that carbon dioxide liquifies naturally on Mars. Below carbon dioxide's triple point of [5.1 atmospheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) it cannot exist in liquid phase at the surface.

I should mention that a few papers several years ago discussed the possibility of frozen CO<sub>2</sub> in the soil creating "pockets" where the pressure *might possibly* rise above the triple point, creating small, temporary pockets of CO<sub>2</sub> as liquid, but I don't think that concept panned out.

Electrolysis of CO<sub>2</sub> is definitely a way to make oxygen, but the method being looked at with the greatest interest is high temperature (800 - 1000 °C) gaseous electrolysis with conductive oxide solid electrodes.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13869/12102) to the question [How to produce oxygen out of Venusian atmosphere's carbon dioxide?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13865/12102) does a good job of outlining some options for obtaining oxygen from atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub>. It points to this very nice, long answer about [MOXIE (Mars OXygen In situ resource utilization Experiment)](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5096/12102) which is a solid electrode, high temperature gaseous CO<sub>2</sub> electrolytic cell which reduces CO<sub>2</sub> to oxygen and carbon monoxide. It is one of the experiments planned for the Mars 2020 Rover. These answers are very well written and *the answer linked for MOXIE contains extensive links for further reading*, so I won't discuss it any more here.

---

Now your question about liquid CO<sub>2</sub>. While I could find some discussion of CO<sub>2</sub> dissolved in other ionic liquids, so far I haven't found anything about trying to do electrolysis on pure liquid CO<sub>2</sub>. Since CO<sub>2</sub> is a stable, covalently bonded molecule, I think we can assume that it will have extremely poor electrical conductivity as a liquid. The reason water works so well is that it dissociates readily - pH 7 means (oh my gosh, I'm going to say something about high school chemistry) one in every roughly 10<sup>-7</sup> of the water molecules is split all of the time, resulting in H<sup>+</sup> (or H<sub>3</sub>O<sup>+</sup>) and OH<sup>-</sup> Add some salt, or other ionic compounds and the conductivity goes up even farther. Liquid CO<sub>2</sub>? possibly no useful conductivity.

It looks like gaseous high temperature electrolysis has been identified as the best way to go on Mars.

---

[image]

**Above:** Phase diagram of CO<sub>2</sub> from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carbon_dioxide_pressure-temperature_phase_diagram.svg).

Comment: While this does address the fact that liquid CO$_2$ does not naturally occur, it does not actually answer the question of whether or not you can use electrolysis to separate the carbon and the oxygen, which is the main point of the question.

Comment: @Phiteros done. If the question improves, I can adjust the answer. There are other methods besides electrolysis to get oxygen from CO2, and there are other several existing answers here about that already. I'm trying to address the part of the question that is unique and new here.

Comment: You should probably put links in your answer to these other questions then.

Comment: @Phiteros OK I'm 'out the door' at the moment, I'll be back here in a few hours. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me on the diagram were electrolysis begins for $CO_2$?

Comment: you must read the link in the question. I know liquid $CO_2$ don't exist as a liquid, but it can be collected and stored as stated link. Thanks

Comment: This was pointed out to me in chemistry.se https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_splitting#Solar-thermal